# I tried to import a csv file in python using pandas but got syntax error

Tags: python, unicode, syntax-error

I used the codes below

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = pd.read_csv('C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\pims-indians-diabetes',header=None, names=['Prognancies','Glucose','BloodPressure','SkinThickness','Insulin','BMI','Pedigree','Age','Outcome'])
print(data.head())
```

The error I got is below. I also tried suggestions for similar questions to no avail

```
File "<ipython-input-11-dd1ac43370f9>", line 3
    data = pd.read_csv('C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\pims-indians-diabetes',header=None,names=['Prognancies','Glucose','BloodPressure','SkinThickness','Insulin','BMI','Pedigree','Age','Outcome'])
                                                                       ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

I tried to resolve the problem using response to similar questions.

I expect some one to look at the codes and error massage and assist me

Comment: Write it as `'C:\\Users\\Admin\\Downloads\\pims-indians-diabetes'`, with double backslashes.

Comment: TL;DR: the `\U` in `'C:\Users...'` is a unicode escape sequence, not the literal characters ``\`` and `U`. Per the dupe, you need to escape the ``\`` or use a raw string.

Answer (score 0):

you have to pass exactly the full path of the `.csv` file like:
`data = pd.read_csv("data/data.csv")`